# Silverstripe - return an array of pages selected with TreeMultiselectField

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to use TreeMultiselectField to associate many pages to one page in Silverstripe. I was able to do that, the CMS saves them. But now I need to  be able to display the pages I selected on the template. How do I do that?
Here's my code so far

```
class FundsAndPerformancePage extends Page {
          public static $many_many = array(
           "Funds" => "SiteTree",
            "Information" => "SiteTree"
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TreeMultiselectField('Funds','Select pages for section "Our Funds"', 'SiteTree'));
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TreeMultiselectField('Information','Select pages for section "More Information"', 'SiteTree'));
        return $fields;
    }

    public function Funds(){

        //Need to return an array of pages selected with TreeMultiselectField

    }
}

class FundsAndPerformancePage_Controller extends Page_Controller {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to loop the related Pages in a template, you don't have to define a getter method yourself.

`<% loop $Funds %>` should work by default, by using the default (magic) getter method `->Funds()`

If you need an array anyway, you could do something like this:

```
public function FundsAsArray(){
    return $this->Funds()->toArray();
}
```

as the getter method returns an instance of `ManyManyList`, which would have an `toArray` method inherited from `DataList`

see http://api.silverstripe.org/3.0/source-class-DataList.html#_toArray

Comment: Hi Mark,
Sorry, it was meant to be "Funds" => "SiteTree" not "Funds" => "Page".
I had tried <% loop $Funds %> before, but for some reason, it was returning an error along the lines of "method Funds not found" on the frontend. So I decided to try Pages instead of SiteTree, but that didn't work, so was meant to change it for the question.

Anyway, <% loop $Funds %> started working this morning as if it was waiting for your magic consent :)

Thanks for the reply